# How to add edges to gridpane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, model-view-controller

I am struggling with writing a program that requires me to make a [nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) game using GUI and MVC design patterns. Since it's a nonogram game, I need to create a grid. A nonogram game would be like this:

[image: game1]

Here's what I got by creating rectangles in GridPane:

[image: game2]

But I have no idea how to add the edges that contain the clues of the game around the gridpane I created.

Here's the code I've had:

```
public class PuzzleView implements FXComponent {

  private Controller controller;
  Model model;

  public PuzzleView(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    model = ((ControllerImpl) controller).getModel();
  }
So
  @Override
  public Parent render() {

    GridPane board = new GridPane();
    double width = 30;
    board.setLayoutX(300);
    board.setLayoutY(300);
    int h = model.getHeight();
    int w = model.getWidth();

    Rectangle[][] rec = new Rectangle[w][h];

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        rec[i][j] = new Rectangle();
        rec[i][j].setX(i * width);
        rec[i][j].setY(j * width);
        rec[i][j].setWidth(width);
        rec[i][j].setHeight(width);
        rec[i][j].setFill(Color.WHITE);
        rec[i][j].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        board.add(rec[i][j], i, j);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Off the top of my head (having to really used JavaFX), you should use a compound layout.  That is, you use a parent container that lays out the "hints" around the container containing the `GridPane`, maybe using a `BorderPane`?  Each edge of the `BorderPane` could then container different layouts panes based on your needs

Comment: First, change `board.add(rec[i][j], i, j)` to `board.add(rec[i][j], i + 1, j + 1)`.  Then you can add the ‘clue’ boxes to row 0 and column 0.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to layouting, there will be more than one approach to address it. You can either choose the ways suggested in comments or you can go with the below approach.

The below approach relies on styling the borders using CSS. This way you can exactly get the look what you are expecting and also works perfectly for any size of board.

Firstly you will separate the hints sections and puzzle section into separate gridPanes. That way you can have more control on individual sections.

And then you style the gridPanes and boxes in grid pane to get the desired stlying. In the second screenshot i added the spacing to showcase how each gridpane and box is styled to achieve the final look.

The key thing is you set each border side width specifically (0px, 1px or 2px). When the final layout is rendered, you get the desired look.

Please check the below demo :

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GridPaneBordersDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
         double width = 30; // each box size
        int rows = 8; // Main box rows & cols
        int cols = 6;
        int topHintRows = 3;
        int sideHintCols = 4;

        // Top hint pane
        GridPane topHint = new GridPane();
        topHint.getStyleClass().add("topHintPane");
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < topHintRows; j++) {
                StackPane box = getBox(width);
                box.getStyleClass().add("topHintBox");
                topHint.add(box, i, j);
            }
        }

        // Side hint pane
        GridPane sideHint = new GridPane();
        sideHint.getStyleClass().add("sideHintPane");
        for (int i = 0; i < sideHintCols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                StackPane box = getBox(width);
                box.getStyleClass().add("sideHintBox");
                sideHint.add(box, i, j);
            }
        }

        // Main Puzzle
        GridPane mainPuzzle = new GridPane();
        mainPuzzle.getStyleClass().add("puzzlePane");
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                StackPane box = getBox(width);
                box.getStyleClass().add("puzzleBox");
                mainPuzzle.add(box, i, j);
            }
        }

        GridPane emptyGrid = new GridPane();
        emptyGrid.getStyleClass().add("emptyGrid");

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        pane.add(emptyGrid,0,0);
        pane.add(topHint,1,0);
        pane.add(sideHint,0,1);
        pane.add(mainPuzzle,1,1);

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Show spacing");
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->{
            double gap = val?10:0;
            Insets insets = val? new Insets(10):Insets.EMPTY;
            Stream.of(pane,topHint,sideHint,mainPuzzle,emptyGrid).forEach(grid->{
                grid.setHgap(gap);
                grid.setVgap(gap);
                grid.setPadding(insets);
            });
            stage.sizeToScene();
        });
        VBox root =new VBox(checkBox,pane);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("grid.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("GridPane Border");
        stage.setOnShown(e->stage.sizeToScene());
        stage.show();

    }

    private StackPane getBox(double width){
        StackPane box = new StackPane();
        box.setMinSize(width,width);
        box.setMaxSize(width,width);
        box.getStyleClass().add("box");
        return box;
    }
}
```

CSS code (grid.css):

```
.emptyGrid{
   -fx-border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.topHintPane{
   -fx-border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.sideHintPane{
   -fx-border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.puzzlePane{
   -fx-border-width: 1px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.box{
  -fx-background-color:transparent ;
}

.topHintBox{
   -fx-border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.sideHintBox{
   -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}

.puzzleBox{
   -fx-border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
   -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

I am again reminding you that, you can achieve with other approaches as well. This is just one way using individual box & gridPane styling.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using JavaFX `Control` (or `Pane`) rather than shape for representing a grid cell, and 4 `GridPane`s to represent the different areas of the board:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MonogramBoard extends Application {

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 5, HINT_SIZE = 2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) {
        Node corner = new Board(HINT_SIZE, HINT_SIZE, false, false).getNode();
        Node topHint = new Board(HINT_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE, true, true).getNode();
        HBox topPane = new HBox(corner, topHint);

        Node leftHint =  new Board(BOARD_SIZE,HINT_SIZE, true, true).getNode();
        Node board = new Board(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE, true, true).getNode();
        HBox bottomPane = new HBox(leftHint, board);
        VBox root = new VBox(topPane, bottomPane);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primary.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primary.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Board{
    private final GridPane grid;

    public Board(int rows, int columns, boolean isBorder, boolean isGridLines) {
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(1));
        if(isBorder) {
            grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black ; -fx-border-width: 2px");
        }else{
            grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: white ; -fx-border-width: 2px");
        }
        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++){
                grid.add(new Cell(isGridLines).getNode(), col, row);
            }
        }
    }

    Node getNode() {return grid; }
}

//represents a single cell
class Cell{
    private final Label label;
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 50;

    Cell(){
        this(true);
    }

    Cell(boolean isBorder){

        label = new Label();
        if(isBorder) {
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black ; -fx-border-width: 1px");
        }else{
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: white ; -fx-border-width: 1px");
        }
        label.setPrefSize(CELL_SIZE,CELL_SIZE);
    }

    Node getNode() {return label; }
}
```

---

[image]